# Trigger click UP or Down input type number with other button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a structure input type number like this

```js
jQuery('.button-plus').click(function(){
    var currentval = parseInt(jQuery(this).prev().val(), 10);
        if (!isNaN(currentval)) {
            jQuery(this).prev().val(currentval + 1);
            }else {
            jQuery(this).prev().val(0);
                }
                    });
                    
jQuery('.button-minus').click(function(){
    var currentval = parseInt(jQuery(this).next().val(), 10);
        if (!isNaN(currentval) && currentval > 0) {
            jQuery(this).next().val(currentval - 1);
                }else {
                    jQuery(this).next().val(0);
                    }
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="-" class="button-minus" data-field="quantity">
<input id=input type=number min=1 max=10>
<input type="button" value="+" class="button-plus" data-field="quantity">
```

but there is a code trigger only if the input type number click instead change value. is there is some way to trigger click input type number without actually click it?

Comment: you demo works, i can't work out exactly what you need, can you try elaborate a bit more please.

Comment: @joshmoto so in my code it's changing the value but there is 3rd party code trigger not because of value input change but because of input type "click", I want a button not only change the value but also trigger click input type number

Comment: Is this for min max validation

Comment: Or you could trigger the up/down keys on the input tho not cleanest option

Comment: @BaimWhello You want to perform a click on the input right? So that other code could be executed ?

Comment: @joshmoto is there any option to change value input type number also trigger click? other 3rd party use on() to run their code.

Comment: @PranavRustagi yes. so I want to change the value input with a button and also automatic trigger on change input type number at the same time.

Comment: Just type the following at the end of both event handlers (button ones) : `$('input').click()`.